# Query to Find Adjacent Date Records

Tags: sql, oracle

There exists in my database a `page_history` table; the idea is that whenever a record in the `page` table is changed, that record's old values are stored in the history table.

My job now is to find occasions in which a record was changed, and retrieve the pre- and post-conditions of that change. Specifically, I want to know when a page changed groups, and what groups were involved in the change. The query I have below can find these instances, but with the use of the min function, I can only get back the values that match between the two records:

```
 select page_id,
       original_group,
       min(created2) change_date
  from (select h.page_id,
               h.group_id original_group,
               i.group_id new_group,
               h.created_dttm created1,
               i.created_dttm created2
        from   page_history h, 
               page_history i
        where  h.page_id = i.page_id
        and    h.created_dttm < i.created_dttm
        and    h.group_id != i.group_id)
 group by page_id, original_group, created1
 order by page_id
```

When I try to get, say, any details of the second record, like `new_group`, I'm hit with a `ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression` error. I don't want to group by new_group, though, because that's going to destroy the logic (I think it would find records displaying times a page changed from a group to another group, regardless of any changes to other groups in between).

My question, then, is how can I modify this query, or go about writing a new one, that achieves a similar end, but with the added availability of columns that do not match between the two records? In essence, how can I find that min record without sacrificing all the other columns I'm not trying to compare? I don't exactly need a complete answer, any suggestions that point me in the right direction would be appreciated.

I use PL/SQL Developer, and it looks like version 11.2.0.2.0 of Oracle.

EDIT: I have found a solution. It's not pretty, and I'd still like to see some alternatives, but if helping me out would threaten to explode your brain, I would advise relocating to an easier question.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your table structure it's hard to re-write the query but when you have a min function used like that it invariably seems better to put it into a separate sub select to get what you want and then compare the result of that.